# Pass a part of DataGrid from form to another with condition

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` (Produit) winth 5 columns (C1,C2 ,C3 ,C4 , C5)Binded to an `ObservableCollection<T>` (DbCollection) populated in `Form` (Vente); Now i want to pass 3 columns (C1, C3,C4) to other `Form` (Confirmation) with condition that `C2!=0 && C3!=0 && C4!=0`. I don't know how to start and where ends please post all the answer cuz i'm kinde of new.
**what i try**
I pass the datagrid to the seconde form and try the folowing

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)myDataGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable;
```

And thene do a foreach and delete the rows but i got an error in the line above.

Comment: What error do you get there? And why not just take the data from the ObservableCollection and display it in the second DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution (there are many) is to filter out the items from your ObservableCollection that meet your conditions, like so:

```
var filtered = DbCollection.Where(r => r.C2 != 0 && r.C3 != 0 && r.C4 != 0);
```

Then pass this to your Confirmation form for display.

Comment: How to pass it to the other form ??

Comment: There are many posts on SO regarding passing data between forms.  I'd start there.